# Display large images on custom tumblr page (not blog posts).

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I have a single page where I am using a mixture of custom html as well as being able to edit the content in the tumblr cms.

If I was working on the main template I know I can write:

```
<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" />
```

But is this possible on a single custom page?

When I add content to the custom page (ie uploading images), this is what my code and the tumblr code looks like:

```
<ul class="slider">
   <li><img src="https://31.media.tumblr.com/918fc65c20cafd6cf23337ad133dc12b/tumblr_inline_njgh7vnP531r2a01g.jpg" />'I just hope I can get back to everybody really soon' - Graphite and ink on paper</li>
   <li><img src="https://31.media.tumblr.com/83fb56103b482e36e7d066a26a93cce8/tumblr_inline_njgh9hsTH41r2a01g.jpg" />'I just hope I can get back to everybody really soon' - Graphite and ink on paper [detail]</li>
   ...
</ul>
```

This is returning images that are 500px wide.

If you need to see more code let me know I can add a link to the current test tumblr.

Comment: AFAIK, no. The Standard Layout uses the Text Post Type. A Custom Layout doesn't allow any theme operators. The work around is not to use the Rich Text Editors image uploader (which limits images to 500px wide) and host the images elsewhere, like Flickr / Dropbox.

Comment: @mikedidthis thank you. I thought this might be the case.

Comment: I was doing something unrelated, but I saw this in the docs `{block:Posts inlineMediaWidth="500"}` : https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts Looks like we can define the inline media size?

Comment: @mikedidthis thank you. I will try and play around with this soon. The client is actually my wife, so we have already talked about a hosted solution.